# how to restrict the UIdatepicker controll in ios swift for past 7 days from current date

Tags: swift3, xcode8, ios10

i m using xcode 8 and ios 10 with swift.I want to restrict UIdatepicker controll as past 7 days from current date.i did add minimumdate() and maximumdate() methods.how to fix this issue.plz let me know,if any one have solution.
Thank you

Comment: You want to select date with in only past 7 days from current date right?

Comment: Could you please post some code?

Comment: Right Nirav sir,Can you tell me the solution.Thank u

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on his own. A good way to show this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).